# ARM assembly: Strange instruction pattern (endless loop?)

Tags: disassembly, assembly, arm

I noticed a strange instruction pattern. First the value of PC is moved into LR and then a register value is moved into PC.

Here some examples:

```
.text:00001488                 MOV             LR, PC
.text:0000148C                 MOV             PC, R2
 ...
.text:000304E8                 MOVNE           LR, PC
.text:000304EC                 MOVNE           PC, R3
```

If this pattern corresponds to a call instruction, wouldn't this result in an endless loop? If this does not correspond to a call, what is this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure if it is a call pattern, but this code is OK because of pipeline and will not create the endless loop. As people quoting [here](https://community.arm.com/thread/2341) from [here](http://liris.cnrs.fr/~mmrissa/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=armv7-a-r-manual.pdf)

> on page A2-11 (Section A2.3) of the manual (ARM Architecture Reference
>   Manual ARMv7-A and ARMv7-R edition) it's been said that:
>
> PC, the program counter
>
> - When executing an ARM instruction, PC reads as the address of the current instruction plus 8.
> - When executing a Thumb instruction, PC reads as the address of the current instruction plus 4.
> - Writing an address to PC causes a branch to that address.
>
> Most Thumb instructions cannot access PC. The ARM instruction set
>   provides more general access to the PC, and many ARM instructions can
>   use the PC as a general-purpose register. However, ARM deprecates the
>   use of PC for any purpose other than as the program counter. See
>   Writing to the PC on page A2-46 for more information. Software can
>   refer to PC as R15

Answer (score 4):

This was actually the correct way to perform indirect calls in ARM before the introduction of the `BLX` instruction (ARMv5 IIRC). ARM(32-bit version) is special in that the value of PC is pointing two instructions ahead when you read it (so +8 in ARM mode and +4 in Thumb mode). So, taking your example:

```
.text:00001488                 MOV             LR, PC
```

here, the `PC` value will be 1488+8 = 1490, so `LR=0x1490`

```
.text:0000148C                 MOV             PC, R2
```

here, the `PC` will be set to the value in `R2` and the processor will start fetching instructions from that address. Most likely it will be a function which ends with a return instruction - `MOV PC, LR` (IDA shows it as `RET`), so the execution will resume at the value of `LR`（0x1490) which happens to be just after the original `MOV PC, R2` instruction (0148C+4=0x1490), so in effect that sequence of instruction is equivalent to `BLX R2` in the newer processors.